# upload text file to google drive using python every 5 seconds

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, text-files, google-oauth, google-drive-api

how can i modify the following python code to upload the ecg.txt  to google drive every 5 seconds where i update  this text file. the code now ask for Oauth every time it upload the file , i want it to ask for authentication only in the first time.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow


# Copy your credentials from the console
CLIENT_ID = XXXXXX
CLIENT_SECRET = XXXXX

# Check https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes for all available scopes
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# Redirect URI for installed apps
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Path to the file to upload
FILENAME = 'ecg.txt'

# Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials
flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)

# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

# Insert a file
media_body = MediaFileUpload(FILENAME, mimetype='text/plain', resumable=True)
body = {
  'title': 'My document',
  'description': 'A test document',
  'mimeType': 'text/plain'
}

file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
pprint.pprint(file)
```

Comment: XXXX out your client ID and secret. I would kill your existing key and get a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the decorator as seen in the video bellow it stores your access token in the db for you and handles refreshing when needed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HoUdWBzUZ-M

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine

```
from oauth2client.appengine import OAuth2Decorator

decorator = OAuth2Decorator(client_id=CLIENT_ID, 
                            client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
                            scope=OAUTH_SCOPE,
                            callback_path=REDIRECT_URI)


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @decorator.oauth_required #Simply place this above any function that requires login.
    def get(self):
```